# Apache - Require authentication for all but one IP

Tags: apache-2.4, whitelist

We have a website that users need a valid jwt token to access however we need a certain IP access WITHOUT the token. Here's what I am trying to use to no avail:

```
<Directory ${VIDEO_ROOT}>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
    AllowOverride All
    <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
    AuthType jwt
    AuthName "private area"
    Require jwt-claim user=genericuser  # username of some kind must exist
    Require valid-user
    </LimitExcept>
    SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "^1\.2\.3\.4" ip_ok
    Allow from env=ip_ok
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

Can any apache gurus help me understand the correct way of doing this? I do need to use X-Forwarded-For

Comment: Using the `RequireAny` and/or `RequireAll` in [Authorization Containers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#logic) allows you to apply logic and combine access controls  in the manner you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @diya the following seems to do the trick:

```
<Directory ${VIDEO_ROOT}>
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
    AllowOverride All
    SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For ^1\.2\.3\.4 ip_ok
    <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
    AuthType jwt
    AuthName "private area"
    <RequireAny>
    Require jwt-claim user=genericuser  # username of some kind must exist
    Require valid-user
    Require env ip_ok
    </RequireAny>
    </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```